# Cannot install code-server onto WSL. "System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate."

Tags: ubuntu, windows-subsystem-for-linux, code-server

I'm following the instructions to download code-server here: https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/v3.8.0/doc/install.md#debian-ubuntu

Because I'm on windows, I'm using Ubuntu on Windows Subsystem for Linux (WSL).

I have successfully run the following two lines:

```
curl -fOL https://github.com/cdr/code-server/releases/download/v3.8.0/code-server_3.8.0_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i code-server_3.8.0_amd64.deb
```

However, I'm having a problem with the last line:

sudo systemctl enable --now code-server@$USER

I get the following error:

```
System has not been booted with systemd as init system (PID 1). Can't operate.
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message indicates that the `.deb` is designed to use systemd, which WSL doesn't support (without a *lot* of extra effort).

However, it appears that `code-server` supports a "standalone" (non-package) based installation.  See [this section](https://github.com/cdr/code-server/blob/v3.8.0/doc/install.md#standalone-releases) of the install doc for details.